# Exception after bin/magento setup:di:compile and adding virtualType

Tags: magento2, di, virtualtype

I was adding this:

```
<virtualType name="Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat\Collection" type="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="mainTable" xsi:type="const">\Test\Faq\Setup\Operation\CreateViewStatTables::TABLE_NAME</argument>
        <argument name="resourceModel" xsi:type="string">Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat</argument>
    </arguments>
</virtualType>
```

instead this class:

```
<?php

namespace Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\Db\FetchStrategyInterface as FetchStrategy;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface as EntityFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface as EventManager;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface as Logger;
use Test\Faq\Setup\Operation\CreateViewStatTables;
use Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\SearchResult
{
    public function __construct(
       EntityFactory $entityFactory,
       Logger $logger,
       FetchStrategy $fetchStrategy,
       EventManager $eventManager,
       $mainTable = CreateViewStatTables::TABLE_NAME,
       $resourceModel = VisitStat::class
   ) {
       parent::__construct(
           $entityFactory,
           $logger,
           $fetchStrategy,
           $eventManager,
           $mainTable,
           $resourceModel
       );
   }
}
```

But after that, when I was compiling di, I see that:

> [ReflectionException]
>   Class Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat\CollectionFactory does
>   not exist
>
> Class Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat\CollectionFactory does
>   not exist
>
> Source class "\Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat\Collection"
>   for "Test\Faq\Model\ResourceModel\VisitStat\CollectionFactory"
>   generation does not exist.

Comment: where are you using this class? I can't see any reference of this class in your question.

Comment: @RamkishanSuthar I just create factory. And after that call parent method